# How to use Web Socket in ios chat application?

Tags: ios, web, websocket

I want to make chat application through web socket.
Is there any link for reference?
are there any steps?
how to setup to server ?

Comment: why negative vote ? what is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial about it, with references to github code - http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps.

Comment: thank you .but it is complex.can you explain steps ?

Comment: can u plz explain how to do server side ?